# Filter words as per confidence level

Tags: c#, kofax

My requirement is to create a process for which Input will be the PDF/TIF files(bulk ingest).Extraction/classification will be done by dedicated (Extraction group).Once we get the document with confidence level ,have to filter only confident words(says > 95% confidence value) and write them in a Text file.As of now KTA doesn't support Full OCR text so have to use GetPagePropertyValues() SDK in a custom dll.Anyone have worked on similar requirement and if there is a better way to do it (custom code perspective ) ?

Answer (score 0):

KTM supports it, you can use KTM script to filter out locator results with the required confidence percentage. Use a script locator to handle it.

Comment: Thanks for the response ,We are preferring not to do it at project level.